# Replace the word at the cursor with a single character?

Tags: normal-mode

An operation I do often in vim is to replace the word at the cursor with a single letter.

Currently, I do this via:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> x <kbd>Esc</kbd>

(Where x is my replacement letter).

This isn't bad, but is there a way to do this without entering insert mode, so that I don't have to hit Escape when I'm done?

Comment: Most answers here will make the workflow like 2 keystrokes, e.g. `,x` (if I mapped the script to `,` and `x` is the replacement letter) and would definitely help -- Just to mention, you may also want to do `inoremap jk <esc>` so it won't feel too much a burden to exit from insert mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rXldw`

Replace the first character with X then move right and delete the rest of the word. No insert mode required.

`rXlde` is actually needed if you are working with a word with trailing space, rather than a delimiter.

Comment: This fails if the word is only two characters long. You can obviously do `rXlx` instead in that situation, but now you have two different series of keystrokes. :(

Comment: I like this solution since it will work at ANY vim I happen to sit down at, not just "my" vim. Thanks!

Comment: @JonSchneider It works with any vi because I'm an ancient vi guy who doesn't know vim at all. So all I have to work with is the original vanilla product.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find a way to do this in the docs, so I created a mapping to do it.  You can type this into your .vimrc file:

```
nnoremap <leader>rw vwhhc.<esc>r
```

Let me break it down:

```
vw -> highlight a word
hh -> go left twice because highlighting a word puts your cursor on the next word, and you don't want to change it
c  -> change what's highlighted (this will delete the word)
.  -> put a period there
<esc> -> go to normal mode
r -> press r on the period.  The next button you press will replace that . with the character you want.
```

Comment: The idea is good, but it could be simplified into `ciw.<esc>r`. If you want to replace a word, `ciw` is the sequence with the less side-effects. You could also have kept OP's `cw` ->  `cw.<esc>r`

Answer (score 5):

There is no builtin solution. And I fail to find a one liner. If I put `eatchar()` directly in a mapping, it'll see what follows in the mapping instead of what the user will type.

The following isn't very ergonomic, but it'll work:

```
function! s:repl1() abort
  let c = nr2char(getchar())
  exe "normal! ciw".c."\<esc>"
endfunction

" use anything you wish instead of "µ" to trigger the mapping    
nnoremap <silent> µ :call <sid>repl1()<cr>
```

EDIT: See Daniel Kaplan's answer for a oneliner

BTW, it's also possible to define our own operator ([`:h g@`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#g%40)), so instead of `µ`, we could type `µiw` (for the current word), `µw` (from the cursor position to the end of the current word), and so on.

```
function! s:opfunc(type) abort
  let motion = a:type == 'line' ? "'[v']" : '`[v`]'
  silent exe "normal! ".motion."c".nr2char(getchar())."\<esc>"
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> µ :set opfunc=<sid>opfunc<cr>g@
```

Note that, I've still haven't found how to force a redraw where we see we're in REPLACE-mode. The best I can come up with is the following, inspired by Daniel Kaplan's solution.

```
  silent exe "normal! ".motion."c¤\<esc>"
  redraw
  silent exe "normal! r".nr2char(getchar())
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an improvement on [Daniel Kaplan's answer.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14276/2920)

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>rw "ciw".nr2char(getchar())."\<esc>"
```

There are a couple improvements here:

1. This uses `ciw` instead of `vwhhc`. This is shorter and more idiomatic, doesn't move your visual selection marks `'<,'>`, and more importantly, works at the end of a word instead of just at the beginning.
2. This doesn't do anything until you choose what character you're replacing the word with.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way (overkill perhaps):

```
command -nargs=1 RW :call ReplaceWord(<f-args>)
fun! ReplaceWord(char)
    sil exe "s/" . expand('<cword>') . "/" . a:char . "/"
endfun
```

Now you can just type `:RW x` with your cursor over the word you want to replace. RW stands for "replace word" but you could choose your own preferred command name.

Answer (score 1):

```
:map , cwx<esc>r
```

`x` is a temporary replacement character.  The `r` at the end leaves it in replace mode to replace the temporary character `x`.

So to change `asdf` to `y` with the cursor on `a` type `,y`